# Ionic: No matching client found for package name org.apache.cordova (Firebase)

Tags: android, cordova, firebase, ionic-framework

I am new to `ionic1 framework` and working on *`sidemenu ionic app`*.     I am trying to make push notifications work through Firebase, with cordova-plugin-fcm for this, I have installed Firebase using

```
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-firebase@0.1.19 --save
```

plugin in my app.

when I run `ionic run android`, it gives build failure error:

```
Execution failed for task ':CordovaLib:processDebugGoogleServices'. No matching client found for package name org.apache.cordova
```

I have searched a lot, but not getting any solutions. Also, I have the same package name in my app config file and google-services.json file.

Please help me. I really need this.

Answer (score 20):

I know it's old but if someone has the same problem, check that your `widget id` in `config.xml` and `package_name` in `google-services.json` are the same.

Answer (score 0):

You need to [follow this tutorial](https://medium.com/@felipepucinelli/how-to-add-push-notifications-in-your-cordova-application-using-firebase-69fac067e821) and end up adding a generated google-services.json file to the root of your project